# Is it important to use localhost/127.0.0.1 rather than machine's own IP address?

Tags: amazon-ec2, localhost, loopback

I'm on Amazon AWS EC2 running Amazon Linux, though that may not be significant to the answer.

Say I have three hosts, H1, H2, H3, with private IP addresses of 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, and 10.0.0.3. This could be represented in a /etc/hosts file with these lines:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
10.0.0.1    H1
10.0.0.2    H2
10.0.0.3    H3
```

In php code I do things like run curl to access stuff on a particular host, based on implicit knowledge of what that hosts offers. I'd rather not concern myself with whether the particular host I'm accessing is the host running the code itself, just access H1, H2, or H3. I *could* use a different /etc/hosts file on each host, changing the line with its private IP address to use the address 127.0.0.1. But is that actually significant? If I use identical /etc/hosts files on all the machines, am I sacrificing any performance or functionality?

Does network access made to a machine's own private IP address actually cause real "external" traffic or is it detected and uses the loopback connector like 127.0.0.1 does anyway? Does the process receiving the request see the originating address as the machine's own private IP address, or does it see 127.0.0.1 anyway?

Comment: Do a traceroute and see?

Comment: @ceejayoz I did use traceroute, and indeed they looked to be the same performance-wise. I was looking for someone with experience to confirm lack of other complications that might not be revealed by traceroute. Sven's answer below also settles the issue of the IP address of the request. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an identical `hosts` file is fine and will have no performance impact, the traffic stays local if you connect to `H1` from `H1`. However, if you connect to `localhost/127.0.0.1`, the source IP will be `127.0.0.1` as well, but if you connect to `H1`, the source IP will be `10.0.0.1` (e.g. in the Apache log).

One difference: Some applications, notably MySQL/MariaDB, switch to using Unix Domain sockets for traffic if you connect to `localhost`, but use the IP stack when using `127.0.0.1` or the actual IP address or hostname of the machine. This is said to have a slight performance benefit, though I've never actually benchmarked this.